# How to open a can of olive oil?

Tags: storage, olive-oil, containers

I have a 900 ml can of Saloio olive oil. I lack any idea of how to open it.

[image]

The top of the tin is more-or-less seamless (see photo), and lacks any sort of indicator as to how this may be accomplished. At the rim, the metal on the top folds over the outside of the tin, and I've tried wedging flat instruments of all manner in there to no avail.

So, I'm wondering: what is the best way to open a container like this?

Comment: Back in the days when motor oil came in metal cans, they sold [spouts that would punch a hole and clip onto the side](http://www.etsy.com/listing/177044515/vintage-oil-can-opener-and-spout) so you pour easily ... I have no idea if anyone made food-safe ones.  It's possible that the company that canned the oil also sells a way of opening/using it.

Comment: I have the same tin - it's a fantastic olive oil - but mine has a plastic pulll-out spout. Check the bottom of it for a red octagonal plastic piece - this is the pull-tab to pull out the spout, and it's attached to the spout cap. You'll need to pierce the spout once it's out and uncapped - squeeze the can to get the oil out.

Comment: Please also note - the oil will go rancid if not used quickly, and will have the potential to make a mess if the can is mishandled. Once open, the oil should be transferred to a tinted glass or a stainless steel container designed to store and dispense olive oil.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately no spout! Just metal all the way around...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using a can punch. Punch a hole on both of the shorter sides on top, one to pour with and the other to allow air flow.

If you are unsure what a can punch is.... [here is a pic](http://www.globeequipment.com/Content/Images/1863_1.jpg)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Growing up, we always called them churchkeys.  No idea why

Comment: @AdeleC - they're most common use until around the 70s was for opening beer cans. For some, that's a religion.

Answer (score 3):

I find that using the corner of my clever nearest the handle to make small holes on two of the corners of the can is best, for me anyway. You can control the size of the holes and make for a more controlled pour. By the way, the churchkey is called that because the pointy end pointed up looks like a steeple.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you can't just use a normal tin-opener?

I mean one like this:

[image: tin opener]

You can take the whole top off the tin that way or use it to make two small holes on opposite sides for pouring / letting air in.